# Making a Recipe for Node package Noble

Tags: node.js, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I'm trying to make a recipe for [Noble](https://github.com/noble/noble).

It includes this optional dependency [xpc-connection](https://github.com/noble/noble/blob/master/package.json#L41).

I'm using `devtool` to make the recipe.

I know that `recipetool` recoginizes that `xpc-connection` does not support Linux and ignores it. I found a bug in oe-core related to that. Patch [here](https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/150330/).

However, when I build the recipe, I get this error:

```
 DEBUG: Executing shell function do_install | npm ERR! 
 ...workspace/sources/noble/node_modules/xpc-connection is not a child of 
/home/sarah/l/l-alpha/build-l/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-oe-linux- 
gnueabi/noble/1.9.1+git999-r0/image/usr/lib
```

I can verify that `xpc-connection` is not in the SRC_URI for the recipe.

If I try to remove `xpc-connection` from the node_modules folder, it reappears on build. How can I prevent it from performing this check for the installation of xpc-connection? It shouldn't be a part of the image packages, because it doesn't support Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the version of node specified by the openembedded layer here - https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/blob/master/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/nodejs/nodejs_8.9.4.bb.

I changed the file name to nodejs_8.1.0.bb to revert the version. I also modified the checksum in that file for the right node package. I have other issues in the Noble recipe, but this one is solved for now.